# How do I transmute (?) a `dyn SomeInterface` into a generic `T` when I have checked that they're the same thing?

Tags: types, rust, casting

I have a `trait Interface` and an `Implementation` that `impl`ements it:

```rust
trait Interface {}

struct Implementation {}

impl Interface for Implementation {}
```

I'm dreaming up this dependency injection library which has Interfaces with default implementations and the possibility to override them with other values.

Now, I'm trying to write this funny function `get_override_for_interface<T>`. If `T` happens to be `dyn I`, where `I` is one of the interfaces that have an "override" (in this example, let's say only `Interface` has an "override"), the function should return `Some` `Box` with the overridden value (of type `dyn Interface`).

Otherwise (if the type has no overrides), the function should return `None`. So, for example:

```rust
// should return Some<Box<dyn Interface>>
get_override_for_interface::<dyn Interface>();

// let's say this one doesn't have any overrides.
// should return None
get_override_for_interface::<dyn OtherInterface>();
```

(note: `dyn Interface` is just one example, the generic function should be also able to return `dyn SomeOtherInterfaceWithAnOverride`)

Here's my attempt at writing such a function.

I'm checking at runtime if `T` is `dyn Interface`, and if so, I'm trying to transmute my value (`dyn Interface`) into `T` before returning it.

```rust
fn get_override_for_interface<T: 'static + ?Sized>() -> Option<Box<T>> {
    // check at runtime if T is dyn Interface
    if std::any::TypeId::of::<T>() == std::any::TypeId::of::<dyn Interface>() {

        let value: Box<dyn Interface> = Box::new(Implementation{}) as Box<dyn Interface>;

        unsafe {
            return Some(
                std::mem::transmute::<Box<dyn Interface>, Box<T>>(value)
            );
        }
    }

    None
}
```

(I can already feel I've done something not good, as `T` is always supposed to be `dyn I` for some interface `I`, but I found no way to constrain this, and T can really be anything. This won't matter though, as the only user of this function will be a macro I'm writing)

Unfortunately, the compiler laughs at my attempt:

```
cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types
  --> src/main.rs:14:17
   |
14 |                 std::mem::transmute::<Box<dyn Interface>, Box<T>>(value)
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: source type: `Box<dyn Interface>` (128 bits)
   = note: target type: `Box<T>` (pointer to `T`)
```

How are they differently sized if they can literally be the same type?

If I remove the whole transmuting business, `let _a: Option<Box<dyn Interface>> = get_override_for_interface::<dyn Interface>();` compiles without complaints, so clearly `T` *can* be `dyn Interface`.

Comment: @sk_pleasant-EliasHolzmann yes, but the compiler isn't smart enough to know that. I only know `T` is `dyn Interface` because of the `if` check, which the compiler doesn't take into account during type-checking. If I remove the transmute, it says `expected type parameter T, found trait object dyn Interface`

Comment: Yeah, you're right, sorry, I misread your code and thought that `value` was a parameter to `get_override_for_interface`.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to first construct `Box<T>` then convert to `Box<dyn Interface>` then back to `Box<T>`? Rust provides `std::any::Any` to help with what you're doing, but it only works on references so you could for example return `Box<dyn Interface>`, and easily get a `&T` from that with `downcast_ref`, but getting a `Box<T>` isn't something available.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this is the solution I found, and it works, but I'm not confident it's the best. Feel free to roast my code and provide better alternatives :) I'm still not entirely used to thinking the Rust way, so perhaps there's some pattern I can use to solve the problem without `unsafe`.

I guess the compiler can't guarantee that `dyn Interface` is the same size as `T`, not entirely sure why.

Instead, I can [`transmute_copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute_copy.html), which doesn't check that the sizes are equal.

My whole `if` branch only applies if `T` is the same as `dyn Interface`, so I know better than the compiler that the sizes are equal. So it should be safe. I hope.

Anyway, this seems to work:

```rust
            return Some(
                std::mem::transmute_copy::<Box<dyn Interface>, Box<T>>(&value)
            );
```

Comment: This is relying on unstable implementation detail - namely, the fat pointers layout. It is highly unlikely to change, but, strictly speaking, this might be UB.

Comment: @Cerberus I'm not sure what you mean; could you please elaborate? The unsafe stuff only happens when I've checked that `T` is `dyn Interface`, so, since they are effectively the same type, shouldn't they always have the same representation? Also, if this is UB, what would be a better approach?

Comment: `Box<dyn Trait>` and `Box<T> where T: Sized` will always have different representations, since the former is fat pointer (data + vtable) and the latter is ordinary pointer (data only), even if `dyn Trait` is in fact `T`. You're currently relying on the fact that the fat pointer is layed out as `(&data, &vtable)`, and de-facto this is true, but not guaranteed.